# Quake 1: frame timer

Tags: frame-rate, timer, floating-point

If  you check Quake 1 source code (`sys_linux.c`), you can see something like this:

```
double          time, oldtime, newtime;

double Sys_FloatTime (void)
{
  struct timeval tp;
  struct timezone tzp; 
  static int      secbase; // new epoch

  gettimeofday(&tp, &tzp);  

  if (!secbase)
  {
    secbase = tp.tv_sec;
    return tp.tv_usec/1000000.0;
  }

  return (tp.tv_sec - secbase) + tp.tv_usec/1000000.0;
}

while (1)
{
  // find time spent rendering last frame
  newtime = Sys_FloatTime ();
  time = newtime - oldtime;

  if (time > sys_ticrate.value*2) // 50 ms * 2
    oldtime = newtime;
  else
    oldtime += time;

  Host_Frame (time);
}
```

Why does Quake do `=` some time and `+=` at other times? I suppose it must be some floating point issue, but `Sys_FloatTime()` returns a double, which is very accurate. It is also adjusted to return seconds from the start of the program, it doesn't count from 1/1/1970. Changing the code to use assignment at all times, doesn't seem to change anything.

EDIT: If you check QW source code, you will see, that `Sys_FloatTime()` is renamed to `Sys_DoubleTime()`. But even if a float was returned, why would using `+=` vs `=` make any difference? IMO, ever using a `float` for something like this was wrong, plain and simple.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing, but it looks like both lines `oldtime = newtime;` and `oldtime += time;` do the same thing. I doubt this is to manipulate `float` calculations, as in the worst case your result might be 0.0001 milliseconds different, which makes absolutely no difference when you are calculating frames. Are `newtime` and `oldtime` defined as `double` as well?

Comment: It's not the same thing. newtime is the current time. Where time is the elapsed time. So for some reason when elapsed time is greater than sys_ticrate.value * 2, whatever this is (linux specific?) they're not adding elapsed time for the next iteration. Maybe it has something to do with the hardware used at that time?

Comment: @user743414 From what I understand, `newtime` is current time of the frame (from the start of the application). `oldtime` is the same, but of the previous frame. `time` is the difference between them. So `oldtime + time == newtime` no? So the statements `oldtime = newtime` is the same as `oldtime = oldtime +time`.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, as I find this topic very interesting.

Comment: @TomTsagk It would be absolutely the same, were it not for floating-point arithmetics. If you want to find the code online google for `Sys_FloatTime`. It looks like an unsuccessful attempt to use floats to me, where they don't belong. Both are `double` yes, added to the code.